# How to disable raw audio capture on chromium based browser?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, web-audio-api

Hi is there anyone who have solved the problem with raw audio capture in chromium based browser? My Laptop uses conexant audio driver which doesn't allow for raw audio capture in any chromium based browser. I've tried to do disable it through flags(now can't find it in chrome://Flags or Edge://Flags) and its start menu properties to disable raw audio capture. If there is anyone who can help me please do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this command line to achieve your needs:

```
--disable-features=WASAPIRawAudioCapture
```

For more details, you could refer to this same case: [Raw audio capture flag](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/raw-audio-capture-flag/m-p/3048056).